# Remove the comma which appears after converting a json array to tuples

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have an array of values within a json array. I wanted to convert those values to pairs of tuples which i already did but for some reason have a comma appearing at the end of every tuple pair. Can someone please guide me on how to remove the comma.

JSON :

```
m=    [
            [
                [
                    -118.221524,
                    34.034603
                ],
                [
                    -118.273798,
                    34.038365
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Researched online to see how can i apply formatting to remove the comma

```
for i in m:
    for j in i:
        lines=tuple(j)
        a = []
        a.append(lines)
        print(tuple(a))
```

Expected:

```
((-118.27373, 34.038352))
((-118.273798, 34.038365))
```

Actual:

```
((-118.27373, 34.038352),)
((-118.273798, 34.038365),)
```

Comment: Single element tuples have that comma to differentiate them from simple grouping brackets. The comma doesn't do anything. It what context does it matter? For presentation?

Comment: For treating them as coordinates while plotting a line on a graph, I was thinking if removing the comma makes a difference but if this is how tuples are suppose to be differentiated, maybe I should leave it as is. What do you suggest?

Comment: The trailing comma doesn't do anything. It's simply there when printed so you can tell it's a tuple. It doesn't actually "exist" or effect anything.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: If you ever wanted to get rid of it for presentation purposes though, you could just unpack the tuple using `*`, or turn it into a list, or `join` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to remove the comma is to not print the tuple itself (i.e. `print(tuple(a))`) as the comma is added by the python implementation to signal that it is a tuple.

Instead, you can create a function that ingests a 1-D tuple (for a simpler example) and creates a custom string that is then printed, a la:

```py
def print_tuple(t):
    s = '(('
    for i, val in enumerate(t):
        s += f'{t[i]}'
        if i != len(t) - 1:
            s += ', '
    s += '))'
    print(s)

# test
a = tuple([1,2,3])
print_tuple_1d(a)  # prints: ((1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: It should be much easier to use `str()`/`repr()` of the tuple than to manually construct the string.

Comment: Honestly, it would be much easier to just use `join`: `", ".join(tuple(a[0]))`, then add some brackets around that as needed.

Comment: Certainly. However, it won't support more bespoke formatting requirements nor multi-dimensional tuples

Answer (score 1):

In Python, tuples are printed (and more or less defined) as having a trailing comma (more on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). You can see the source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2491134029b195d3159a489e1803ee22a7839b41/Objects/tupleobject.c#L303) that actually writes the `repr` of a tuple object (assuming you're using a CPython interpreter).

Though, if you're willing to forgo using a a tuple and instead use a list (which it looks like you're already trying to do) you can instead do this:

```py
for i in m:
    for j in i:
        lines=tuple(j)
        a = []
        a.append(lines)
        # Notice this prints `a` which is an array and not a tuple
        print(a)

# prints:
# [(-118.27373, 34.038352)]
# [(-118.273798, 34.038365)]
```

If you do indeed want to use a tuple, you're best bet is likely then to do some manual formatting on the outer tuple like so:

```py
for i in m:
    for j in i:
        lines=tuple(j)
        a = []
        a.append(lines)
        # Notice this prints `a` which is an array and not a tuple
        a = tuple(a)
        print("({})".format(a[0]))

# ((-118.221524, 34.034603))
# ((-118.273798, 34.038365))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although I wouldn't use a list just to "get rid" of the comma. Tuples do have their benefits.

Comment: "a visual cue that you are printing a tuple and not a set" Could you elaborate a bit? Sets are distinguished by curly brackets, so I'm not sure what tuples have to do with them.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking in python 2 where sets are printed with parens (but also `set` prefixed to the parens). I've updated the answer with a link to the docs that talks about tuples and why they have the trailing comma.